# Creating vector elements using boost::make_shared not working correctly

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I have a large number of objects to create and they will all be stored in one particular vector. So I did this:

```
std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<MyClass>> t;
t.resize(5000);
```

I then wrote a script to generate the C++ for creating all 5000 objects:

```
t[0] = boost::make_shared<MyClass>(4659);

t[1] = boost::make_shared<MyClass>(45029);

t[2] = boost::make_shared<MyClass>(2731);
.
.
t[4999]....
```

However, at the end I loop through and it appears I have not constructed the objects correctly:

```
for(boost::shared_ptr<MyClass> s : t){
    //I cannot see the data members for s when debugging here
    s->doSomething(x);
}
```

and it seems `s` is not instantiated.

Have I mis-used `boost::make_shared` and I am not actually creating objects?

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please? I don't see anything obviously wrong with your code.

Comment: @Praetorian the only part of the code I haven't put is the definition of MyClass. This is part of an inheritance hierarchy and I created default constructors for the parent class and MyClass- the default constructors do absolutely nothing.

Comment: Well then it should be really easy to create a test case that demonstrates the problem :)

Comment: Ok- solved it. @Praetorian you may take all the credit. I passed the vector in to a function to populate it with the scripted C++ and I forgot to pass-by-reference :)

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to generate C++ code for this.  Given your example, you should simply generate a text file containing the integers to construct the items with, then do this:

```
vector<shared_ptr<MyClass>> t;
for (int x; cin >> x; ) {
    t.push_back(make_shared<MyClass>(x));
}
```

Of course you could use any istream instead of `cin`.

If you do this, I promise you will not have any "missing" elements in your vector.

Comment: If you throw in a call to `vector::reserve` this is even going to be faster than the original.

Comment: Sure, if you know how many elements are coming.  If you don't, it's probably not worth worrying about, since the cost of copying shared_ptrs is not too high.  And yes, you could read the file once to get the count, but it's probably premature optimization.